# Transaction failure when using Stellar Go SDK

Tags: horizon, transactions, go-sdk

receiving the following errors related to horizon server:

```
 handshake-1 env.sh[19791]: 2019/04/25 12:03:24 handlers.go:180: [ERR] Horizon error: "Transaction Failed". Check horizon.Error.Problem for more information.
 handshake-1 env.sh[19791]: 2019/04/25 12:03:24 handlers.go:188: [ERR] mutator:2 failed: couldn't load account for auto sequence: load account failed: Horizon error: "Resource Missing". Check horizon.Error.Problem for more information.
Apr 25 12:03:24 handshake-1 env.sh[19791]: 2019/04/25 12:03:24 handlers.go:195: [ERR] mutator:2 failed: couldn't load account for auto sequence: load account failed: Horizon error: "Resource Missing". Check horizon.Error.Problem for more information.
```

---

```
// Send transaction from a server account to a new account.
if _, err = stellarClient.CreateWallet(public, DefaultAmount); err != nil {
log.Println("[ERR]", err)
c.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}

// Add server account at a signer to a new account.
if _, err = stellarClient.AddServerToSigners(
private, stellarClient.ClientAccountAddress()); err != nil {
log.Println("[ERR]", err)
c.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}

// Create trust line to asset for a new account.
if _, err = stellarClient.CreateTrustLine(private, DefaultAsset); err != nil {
log.Println("[ERR]", err)
c.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}
```

---

Please explain why these three stellar commands do not work.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've provided I can't tell you why those commands don't work, since they are your custom code, not part of the standard SDK.

First error: It seems pretty clear that the account is not being created for some reason. You need to follow the advice and check `horizon.Error.Problem` to find out what you did wrong.

Second and third error: Since the account didn't get created, these will fail (you can't load an account that doesn't exist).